# PerfView not able to capture custom ETW events

Tags: events, etw-eventsource, perfview

I have a demo solution which raises events by using System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource class. The class I have is as below:-

```
[EventSource(Guid = "B6741490-9F53-4620-A45C-49004C1B4444", Name = "DemoEvent")]
sealed public class DemoEventSource : EventSource
{
    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords = EventKeywords.None)]
    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        this.WriteEvent(1, "Found");
    }
}
```

I followed the steps given [here](http://www.aaronstannard.com/creating-your-own-ETW-source/) to use PerfView tool to view the events being generated by this solution. I have given `*DemoEvent` in the additionalProvider section of the PerfView. However, I am not able to see these events in the output of PerfView. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: you have to pass the Level value to perfview or remove the Level from the Event

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I removed level from event, but it didn't work.

Comment: also remove keyword. also try to use the GUID instead of the name

Comment: any update? Does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

The argument types of your method and argument types of your call to write event must match (adding one integer first argument as you have for the event id) so the auto-generated event source metadata match. i.e.

> ```
> [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords = EventKeywords.None)]
> public void RaiseEvent(string message)
> {
>     this.WriteEvent(1, message);
> }
> ```

Avoid providing a GUID. It is recommended in [the Event Source programming guide from the .NET authors](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/44/08/22/_EventSourceUsersGuide.docx) that you only provide the name and let the GUID be automatically generated from the name.

Make sure you are using [the latest PerfView release from GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases) rather than the obsolete version on Microsoft Downloads.